# Execution error while trying to run Fiddler for mac

Tags: macos, fiddler

I've installed fiddler for mac and the mono framework. I also followed the install instructions pdf included in the download

While running

```
$ mono --arch=32 Fiddler.exe
```

I get

```
Thunderbolt
/Users/XXX/dev/fiddler-mac/FiddlerAttach.applescript:7:87: execution error: /bin/sh: Ethernet,127.0.0.1,8888,on,127.0.0.1,8888,on,0,0,off,0,0,off: command not found (127)
```

The UI does launch and when I try to start capturing traffic, the same error repeats in the terminal